# How to exclude any zero within a vector and values after two consecutive zeros?

Tags: r, diff

There's a little thing that I have a lot of problems with: let's say I have a random 10x10 matrix with column `a` as you see below. What I now want to do is to exclude any row containing a zero in column `a`. Also, any values after two consecutive zeros have to be excluded so that `b` is the target vector I want.

```
a <- c(13, 7, 2, 0, 4, 3, 0, 0, 5, 8)

b <- c(13, 7, 2, 4, 3)
```

I already tried applying the `diff` function with different `lags` but nothing really worked out so far. I appreciate any help!

2nd example: `d <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.8, 0, 0, 0.4, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.1, 0, 0.1, 0.1)`

The first ten elements should not be included. Maybe, I forgot to mention that I want to exclude all values right after the FIRST two consecutive zeros.

Comment: In the 2nd example, then none of the elements would be included, right because there are 4 consecutive 0's at the beginning?  If it is only 2 consecutive 0's then after the 5th element, ie. 0.8, there are 2 consecutive 0's sorry, I am so confused with your `first ten elements should not be included`

Comment: 0.8 0.4 0.5 0.1 0.1 0.1 is what it spits out. It's just that the 0.8/0.4 is too much, it doesn't exclude ANY value after the first two cons. zeros (starting from the behind on this one). The thing is that I have to start excluding zeros starting backwards on this vector for example, if you understand what I mean: keeping both 0.1, skipping the zero, keeping 0.1 and 0.5, that's all, because two zeros follow

Comment: As I mentioned in the earlier comment, the first 2 consecutive 0's occur after 0.8.  What is your expected output

Comment: 0.5 0.1 0.1 0.1
is what I want

Comment: In your second example, isn't 0.5 after two consecutive 0s and therefore should be removed?

Comment: as weird as it sounds, it's about going backwards..let's say having a dataframe with 200 rows, starting in row 100 and going upwards to row 1.

Comment: @rapuu Did you meant that the first 2 consecutive 0's from backwards?

Comment: @akrun exactly that

Comment: So the two examples correspond to 2 different questions, the first is about removing what is after two consecutive zeros and the second about removing what is before two consecutive zeros?

Comment: Couldn't have said it better, sorry for the confusion, very confused myself.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include both cases.

Comment: it's just that I have a dataframe with 10 cols and 200 rows and starting from a given point I have to go up in one column while in the other column I have to go down, excluding any zeros and stopping right after I hit two consecutive zeros.

Comment: Try `d1 <- rev(d);d2 <- d1[!cumsum(d1 == 0)>=2];rev(d2[d2!=0])
#[1] 0.5 0.1 0.1 0.1`

Comment: @Lamia The two codes work perfectly. There's just one more thing I need help with. Is there a way of making your code start from a certain point within the vector, let's say starting in row 100?

Comment: Apply it to `a[100:length(a)]` instead of applying it to `a`. If you want to keep rows 1 to 99 untouched in the beginning, then do `c(a[1:99],b)`.

Comment: @akrun mhh, the first 10-20 values are not correct, seems like it summed up some values

Comment: @Lamia hey, it's me again, is there a way of keeping the whole row while looking for zeros only in the first column?

Comment: There is no immediate adaptation of this method to a dataframe. It would have to be modified a lot. Had you specified your question from the beginning, I would have answered quite differently, probably using `rle`.

Comment: Alright. I'll try to work it out myself somehow, not quite sure I'll make it! Thanks!

Comment: The format on SO is not suited for new questions within comments. If you have a separate question, you should post it as such.

Answer (score 2):

We can use

```
a[cumsum(a == 0)<2 & a!=0]
#[1] 13  7  2  4  3
```

To get the other values

```
a[cumsum(a == 0)>2 & a!=0]
#[1] 5 8
```

---

Or another option is

```
library(data.table)
a1 <- a[seq_len(which((a== 0) & (shift(a, fill =0, type = 'lead')==0))-1)]
b <- a1[a1!=0]
b
#[1] 13  7  2  4  3
```

Comment: @rapuu  Updated the post

Comment: Mhh, I applied the 2nd code to my actual data but it still included values "before" the two consecutive zeros appeared.

Comment: @rapuu You meant the `a[cumsum(a == 0)>2 & a!=0]`.  Could you update your question with another example to check

Comment: Done, sorry for not writing the vector correctly @akrun

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove every single 0 and everything that comes after two consecutive 0s, you could do it this way: converting your vector to a string with numbers separated by commas, using a regular expression to remove unwanted elements, and then convert back to numeric vector form:

```
## gsub("0\\,|(0\\,){2}.*","",..) removes every 0 and every two zeros followed by anything
a = c(13,7,2,0,4,3,0,0,5,8)
b = as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(gsub("0\\,|(0\\,){2}.*","",paste0(a,collapse=",")),",")))
```

This returns:

```
[1] 13  7  2  4  3
```

If you want to remove every single 0 and everything that comes BEFORE two consecutive 0s:

```
d = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.8, 0, 0, 0.4, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.1, 0, 0.1, 0.1)
c = as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(gsub("0\\,|.*(0\\,){2}","",paste0(d,collapse=",")),",")))
```

This returns:

```
[1] 0.5 0.1 0.1 0.1
```

Comment: using this code it says: numeric(0), used on the 2nd example I edited in the original post. @Lamia